# Echo database value in specific color based on value

Tags: html

I have a very basic database and the value is input from a drop menu, the value is 1 of 3 options.
When I output this value in a webpage I want it to be a specific color based on each value.

So if $rows['Away'] value  is Very High  I want the color to be Red,
Medium High  color to be yellow  , Medium Low to be green , font size to remain same, thank you

````
<td><font size=5 color=DD0000 /><b>".$rows['Away']."</b></font></td>
</tr>";```
````

Comment: `$rows['Away']` is not meaningful in HTML, except as the literal text itself. You should probably mention what server software is doing interpolation or preprocessing on this file before it's presented to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you use PHP, assumed that you have a correct way to show the dynamic values to HTML.

I suggest user class to show correct color or some style if you want:

```html
echo '<td class="'.$rows['Away'].'">'.$rows['Away'].'</td>'
```

Example `.$rows['Away'].` is `some-value`, your CSS:

```
.some-value {
  color: red;
  font-size: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

*Note: if `.$rows['Away'].` is the normal text like `Some Value`, let implement a function to convert to `some-value` if any.*